# In any triangle ABC, the expression $(a + b + c) (a + b - c) (b + c - a) (c + a - b)$ is equal to

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

In any triangle ABC, give an equivalence to the expression 
$$(a + b + c) (a + b - c) (b + c - a) (c + a - b)$$

Can somebody help me?

Note that
$$\mathrm{area\,of\,triangle}=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$
where
$s=(a+b+c)/2$

Comment: It's unclear what the question is. What is $r4? Is ABC supposed to be a triangle?

Comment: You want to find an equivalence of the expression, in terms of $s$ and $r$? What is $r$ in the first place?

Comment: Have you heard about Heron's formula?

Comment: area of triangle =2r*2r*2r*2r =16r @lab bhattacharjee

Comment: Area = √( s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c) ) where s=a+b+c/2

Comment: @burm1 Which grade are you in?

Comment: you mean school?

Answer (score 4):

This is nothing but the Heron's formula and $s-c={1 \over 2}(a+b+c)-c=\frac 12(a+b-c)$

So, $(a+b-c)=2(s-c),(a+b+c)=2s$,$(a+c-b)=2(s-b),(c+b-a)=2(s-a)$

So the product gives $16s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$ is 16 times the square of the area of the triangle.

Comment: Do you mean $8$ times, or $16$ times?

Answer (score 3):

Sustituting $s$ in the equation, we have
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)&=&(2s)(2s-2c)(2s-2b)(2s-2a)\\
&=&16\cdot s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)\\
&=&16\cdot A^2
\end{array}$$

where $A$ is the area of the triangle, given by Heron's formula,
$$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$